# Xcode Analyze 69 potential memory leaks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm making my first app and it's really confusing.

I am using ARC, and probably ALL of my potential leaks say:
"Object leaked: object allocated and stored in 'point' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1"

They are on almost any object I create using [[alloc] init].

Any suggestions about how to handle those? The app works fine, though.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the analyzer isn't aware that you're using ARC. You ought to be able to tell it somehow.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your project is actually set to ARC? Those types of analyzer warnings sound like it isn't. Is this a new project where ARC was automatically turned on for you or did you do the conversion for it yourself?

[image: ARC project settings]

There isn't a way to actually tell the analyzer that you are ARC or aren't. It will just pick that up from the settings automatically.

Comment: Yeah It's checked. I started my project on top of ready library - and I can't tell if it is convert or turned on.